# Switch case is been called multiple times

Tags: android

I am facing problem, but I am not getting why **switch case** is been called multiple times. SO for this purpose I am uploading full file.

In logcat this line is been shown multiple times

> 03-01 17:23:31.861 10958-11008/com.example.akki.assignment2 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40d3810

```
 package com.example.akki.assignment2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements       LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {


private static final String TAG = null;
LatLng myPosition;
int Request_Code_Ask_Location = 123;
Location location;
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


boolean isGPSEnabled;
boolean isNetworkEnabled;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

//setSilent(silent);
// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


private void dialogbox() {
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

dialog.setTitle("My Address Information")
        .setMessage("Would you like to see your address information?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //mMap.clear();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationDetails.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
                bundle.putDouble("longitude", longitude);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                // mMap.clear();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        })
        .show();


setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);


}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the     camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be  prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once  the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onPause() {

 super.onPause();


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
System.exit(0);

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, String[]  permissions, int[] grantResults) {
 Toast.makeText(this,"REquest: " + requestcode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

switch (requestcode) {
    case 0:

    {

        if (grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            // onResume();

        } else if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "In else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // boolean shouldshow1 =  ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            boolean shouldshow = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            if (shouldshow == false) {
               RequestPermission();
                /*Toast.makeText(this,"Go to App setting to enable permission or Press Device Back Button to Exit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                //   onBackPressed();

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            // System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    default:
        Toast.makeText(this,"default case",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
//        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions,  grantResults);

}


private void RequestPermission() {

 AlertDialog.Builder dialog2;
dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog2.setCancelable(false);
Log.e("Error", "In rp");
Toast.makeText(this, "In reqestpermission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

dialog2.setTitle("Permission")
        .setMessage("You need to allow acess to  your location")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //mMap.clear();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        })
        .show();


setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);


}
//         return;


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {


if (mMap == null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "no map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  mMap.clear();
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "In checkself", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_Code_Ask_Location);  //to ask permission 6.0


    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}


// mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);


// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// getting network status
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Is Off");                             //To enable GPS

    alertDialog.setMessage("Please Enable GPS for better Location");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();

}

{

    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 25f, this);

        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 25f, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
  /*  String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,  true).toString();
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  1000L, 100.0f, this);
   //   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 10f, this);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);*/

//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


if (location != null) {
    onLocationChanged(location);
}

     // latitude = location.getLatitude();

 //      longitude = location.getLongitude();
Timer t = new Timer(false);   //To show dialogbox after required time
if (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) {
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    dialogbox();

                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);

}

if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
    myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition));
    //mMap.clear();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 16));
}


}
```

Comment: you forgot a break after `case 0: ` and before the `default` keyword

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `break` after each case

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, String[]  permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"REquest: " + requestcode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (requestcode) {
        case 0: {
            if (grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // onResume();
            } else if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "In else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // boolean shouldshow1 =  ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                boolean shouldshow = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                if (shouldshow == false) {
                    RequestPermission();
                    /*Toast.makeText(this,"Go to App setting to enable permission or Press Device Back Button to Exit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    //   onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                // System.exit(0);
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            Toast.makeText(this,"default case",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        //        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions,  grantResults);
}
```

}